# What data / metadata can be read from a PIN protected SIM without entering the PIN?

Tags: embedded, gsm, sim-card, iot

I am building a device with GSM Modem and a SIM card. I would like to protect the SIM card with a pin to prevent its misuse when the devices are installed on field.

Storing the pin for associated SIM into each device would be cumbersome. Also, if SIM is replaced, I want the device to automatically know the PIN for the new SIM. So I was thinking of using a one way hash function to generate the pin from one or more properties of the SIM like its IMSI, ICCID, SIM Card Group Identifier, Service Provider Name etc.

When a SIM is inserted, the device can dynamically calculate the correct PIN based on these properties.

(I know that security based on secret algorithm violates the basic principles of computer security, but in this case I don't need it to be fool proof - I just need something better than leaving it unprotected.)

The problem is that none of these properties can be read before entering the PIN.
Is there any other property that can be read without entering the PIN? Or do you have any work around that does not require storing of PIN on the device in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to generate the PIN using the SIM properties itself (assuming you have relation with the card vendor and the operator).

```
PIN = some_function(sim_properties)
```

Regarding each properties that you mentioned:

1. ICCID - yes, this unique per card. No read restriction and cannot be updated. First choice to use.
2. IMSI - unique per card but cannot be used. You need to provide PIN to read this file.
3. SPN - yes, can be used as well, but is not unique per card. If you want to use this file, ensure that it will not be updated by operator via OTA (Over The Air) RFM (Remote File Management).
4. GID - this file is optional, better not to use it.

For the function itself, I propose using cryptographic hash instead only hash, to give more security.

Additionally, you may also ask the card vendor to add additional proprietary file (EF), which you can put additional data inside (additional keys, bitmasks, key index of master keys to be used, etc).

At the final step, do not forget to convert the cryptographic hash result into numeric format 4-8 digits.

Comment: All that is fine. But these fields cannot be accessed if the SIM is pin protected. If I put a pin protected SIM in the device, the device should be able to calculate its PIN based on some parameters of the SIM. For this to work, those parameters should be readable without entering the PIN.

Comment: ICCID is not pin protected. Refer to 3GPP 11.11 specification section 10. For ICCID, refer to section 10.1.1

Comment: Is it? If so, problem solved. Will check and get back. Thanks.